# Sitecore Hosting using Blue Green Deployment on Azure

Tags: deployment

We are currently having Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 which runs on Azure on PAAS. We are planning to implement Blue/Green deployment for zero downtime  The plan is to have 2 set environments as Blue will have 1CM, 2 CDs (active) and Green will have 1CM, 2 CDs (standby).

My question is has anyone has implemented this type of set up before? How could you keep two Web databases(Blue & Green) in sync with this kind of approach

Comment: If you would like to consider the indexing impacts of blue/green, have a look at this slide deck from Bill Cacy: https://twitter.com/bill_cacy/status/1050809727666536449

Comment: I would say xConnect is not impacted by a few test entries, but probably need to ask client about this...

Answer (score 5):

Whilst your proposed setup is certainly possible with the help of a traffic manager, I would recommend using Deployment slots for blue green deployment.

With deployment slots, you deploy to a different slot, warm up your site and then swap the new code into production without downtime.
In this scenario, there is no need to sync databases.

If you want content-safe deploys you might want to follow this scenario.

1. Create copy of your web database.
2. Deploy code version 1 to you staging slot, link it to the copy of the web database.
3. Swap your staging and production slot. (Visitors are now temporary browsing on web-db copy)
4. Deploy code version 2 to your staging slot, linked with original databases.
5. Test new code and swap into production.

[image: Deployment Slots]

Comment: So every time you are doing deployment database are kept in sync by coping live database

Comment: Essentialy, yes. But beware, we only do this with the web database where we temporary set traffic on a copy, but the CM is always attached to the principle web-db. So no data gets lost and publishes will keep working (but will only go live after switching back to principle database). You don't want to do this with your master, or exm or other databases holding user data.

Comment: how do we handle Sitecore Xconnect & other databases will they be shared across Blue & Green Environments

Comment: As they hold user data, we do not use copies of them, so yes, we share them.

Comment: How is this possible technically to share Xconnect & other databases between Blue & Green environments. Could you throw some lights on this